# how to limit selection with select

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2019

I tried using `limit` order to get a result like

```
student_id | name  |  major
     1     | kate  | bio
     2     | david | chem
     3     | jake  | math
```

instead of

```
student_id | name  |  major
     1     | kate  | bio
     2     | david | chem
     3     | jake  | math
     4     |  ...  | ...
     5     |  ...  | ...
```

which means 3 results instead of 5 but i got a syntax error and couldn't find solutions. any suggestions?

Comment: Show the query you are using.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't use `LIMIT`, is uses `TOP`.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server uses `SELECT TOP` or `OFFSET/FETCH` to limit rows.  So, your query should look like:

```
select top (3) t.*
from t
order by student_id;
```

Note that the `ORDER BY` is important if you care about *which* rows you want.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You need an `ORDER BY` if you care about the ordering.